# ftputil throwing "530 Please login with USER and PASS" error on login with blank credentials while ftplib does not

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib, ftputil

Getting the following error when trying to connect to ftp host with `ftputil`:

> ftputil.error.PermanentError: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.

However I do not get this error when connecting with `ftplib`. I would like to use `ftputil` for some of its additional functionality.

```py
import ftputil
import ftplib

host = 'ftp.swpc.noaa.gov'
user = ''
pw = ''
# works
ftp_host = ftplib.FTP(host, user, pw)
ftp_host.login()
# does not work
ftp_host = ftputil.FTPHost(host, user, pw)
# with ftputil.FTPHost(host, user, pw) as ftphost:
#     ftphost.listdir(ftphost.curdir)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ftplib converts a blank user name to "anonymous". Apparently, ftputil doesn't. By changing the user name, it works

```
import ftputil

host = 'ftp.swpc.noaa.gov'
user = 'anonymous'
pw = ''
with ftputil.FTPHost(host, user, pw) as ftphost:
    print(ftphost.listdir(ftphost.curdir))
```

output:

```
['pub']
```